# How to create auto-show popup which can be interacted with

Tags: javascript, html, css

In our app, we have a persistent search box for which we want to show a help popup whenever the user is focused in the search box.  When the user submits the search or focuses off the search box, the popup should auto-hide.  That part is pretty easy, I'm just using focusin and focusout events to show and hide the popup, as you would expect. You can see how we have it working below:

[image: Popup Off]

[image: Popup On]

#### The Problem

Where things get tricky is, the content of the popup is interactive and clicking anywhere in the popup will fire the focusout event which closes the popup.  I've managed to hack my way around that by detecting when they have clicked in the popup and suppressing the close statement.  This allows the user to have mouse interactions with the popup but itself creates a new problem.  Because the focus is no longer on the search box, if the user clicks anywhere outside the popup, this doesn't fire the focusout event and close the popup as it normally does before they interact with it.

So I'm looking to brainstorm workarounds for this, so that the popup will show whenever the user selects the search box, but still be able to interact with it, but also still have it close when they click anywhere other than the popup or the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an alternative idea. You can either add two event listeners (on focus out and on leaving the list) or you listen to an alternative element, that should be arround the search and the list. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/uh37pmys/2/

Sample html:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <ul>
        <li>Fancy</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some javascript example:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var list = container.querySelector("ul");

var closeModal = function(event){
   // your check if event.target was in container...
    if(container.contains(event.target))
        return;

    list.classList.remove("open");
    document.removeEventListener("click", closeModal);
}

container.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event){
    list.classList.add("open");
    document.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
})
```